# Pandas adding columns: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

With the  code at the bottom of the post I am getting the below error message - any ideas how to solve or why this is happening? The source data already has "Date" and "Value" populated. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = df[['Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value']]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Code Used:

```
import pandas

path = r'H:/Hello.xlsx'

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(path)

# add series
df['Form_ID'] = 'TESTID'

# order columns
df = df[['xl', 'Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value']]

# export dataframe
df.to_excel(path, index=False)
```

Comment: It seems `read_excel` is loading all the sheets (this is supposed to happen when you pass `sheet_name=None`) to a dictionary of DataFrames. Do you have multiple sheets?

Comment: Nope just the one sheet :) called "Sheet1"

Comment: Try changing `df = pd.read_excel(path)` to `df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')`

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. It should start with `import pandas as pd`. Can you post the **exact** code you are using?

Comment: Hi JPP, all sorted - just needed to change my python interpreter location!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reindex_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html), in your case:

`df = df.reindex_axis(['xl', 'Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value'], axis=1)`

that `1` is to tell Pandas to reindex the columns, not the indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why wouldn't `df = df[['xl', 'Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value']]` work?

Comment: Yes, I checked and apparently Pandas allows that, but I think there's something missing in that code. For example it uses `import pandas` but then call it as `pd`